# Spock/Groovy - Condition evaluation order

Tags: spock, maven-surefire-plugin

I have some tests like:

```java
when:
testedFunction()

then:
noExceptionThrown()
1 * service.action()
```

When I run the test, it fails, because some code in `testedFunction` throws an exception.  In the test results (via `maven-surefire-plugin`), the failure is that `service.action()` was never called.  But I don't get any test failure about the exception being thrown.

If I remove the `1 * service.action()` line, then I get a test failure about the exception being thrown, and I can easily debug what the actual issue is

Is there some logic to which conditions it chooses to evaluate first/report? I would have expected either that it should report the first condition that fails, or report all of them.  I can't find any setting to report all vs one either, but I'm not super familiar with spock.

Minimal example, not sure if there's a place to put this since meetspock.appspot.com is broken

```java
import spock.lang.*

class MyFirstSpec extends Specification {
  class Example {
    public function1() {
       throw new Exception("");
    }
  }
  interface Service {
    void func();
  }
  def "should give an exception failure"() {
    given:
    def service = Mock(Service)
    def ex = new Example()

    when:
    ex.function1()

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
    1 * service.func()
  }
}
​
```

Comment: Please add proof to your claims by means of a complete, minimal reproducer. Otherwise, what you are saying does not sound very plausible to me. Probably, there is a bug in your test rather than in Spock.

Comment: @kriegaex added but, it's just doing exactly what I said...

Comment: https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/ is the replacement for meetspock.appspot.com

Comment: @zacaj but adding the example made it easy to just write the response without me having it to do it myself, making it much more likely to get a response - as you now did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into an edge case of Spock.

Interaction conditions, such as `1 * service.func()` are always evaluated first regardless of the order of other conditions. As you also used `noExceptionThrown()`, the exception thrown during the execution actually catched and later asserted, but that doesn't happen as interactions have priority. If you'd removed the `noExceptionThrown()` then you'd actually see it. Therefor, it I'd advise against using `noExceptionThrown()` unless it is the only statement in the `then` block, as it is implied in every other case.

If you want the `noExceptionThrown()` to be evaluate first, you need to use [invocation ordering](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.3/all_in_one.html#_invocation_order_2) as mentioned in the docs, i.e, putting the interaction in a second `then` block.

```java
import spock.lang.*

class MyFirstSpec extends Specification {
  class Example {
    public function1() {
       throw new Exception("");
    }
  }
  interface Service {
    void func();
  }
  def "should give an exception failure"() {
    given:
    def service = Mock(Service)
    def ex = new Example()

    when:
    ex.function1()

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()
      
    then:
    1 * service.func()
  }
}
```

[Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxdkMtuwyAQRfd8xcgryMJStq26bHdZJT9A8RCPSgABflRV_r08bKsqEhJw7lzmDqOHdyFB9E599Ubae39iTBkZI1y-PyjEdPWoANeEdohQLqRJyUTOwg8DaNr3VT68wfoC4KdPQwr0ZFXRnbnYQF5pDG4Bi0uuUegL510nXit_srbJJgxaKoQrhpnUbjw7GqotrwVFOqCGLo5uMgPcaUaQNne7OYOWZKaA3dFBkdiXeiyVcbN_g0seAN9-EwfHNaPWbA3IBatsGXcXXPs_ORtNB7XuSHkrwS0X2yD-Cc9w2pvpW8Ca78nYPri6fgEfl36S)