# How to count Spock Interactions with two different mocks?

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spock

I'm having trouble getting Spock test working. I would like to know how to count two different mocks interactions.

I understand that interactions require mocking. However in my case I have two mocks to deal with. Please see the example code below.

I want to make sure that my `ReportService.makeReport` is called once when `AccountService.findUser` throws an exception.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Service
// others...
public class AccontService {

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public Account findUer(Stirng acccountId) throws CustomInvalidExceptionA, CustomInvalidExceptionB {
    this.restTemplate.postEntity(/* some params */);
    // other logics
    throw new CustomInvalidExceptionB("Parent Account does not qualify");
  }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
// others...
public class SomeHelper {
  @Autowired
  private InventoryService inventoryService;

  @Autowired
  private AccountService accountService;

  @Autowired
  private ReportSerice reportService;

  public ProcessRequest requst(String accountId, Item item) {
    try {
      Account acct = this.accountService.findUser(accountId);
      this.inventoryService.check(item);
    } catch (CustomInvalidExceptionA | CustomInvalidExceptionB ex) {
      Report report=this.reportService.reportRequest(accountid, item, ex.getClass());
      log.error("ERROR" + ex.getClass());
      //Other logics using report object
    }
  }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Service
// others...
public class ReportService {
  public Report reportRequest(String accountId, Item item, String message) {
    // some logics to make a report request
    return // Report object
  }
}
```

```java
class SomeHelperSpec extends Specification {
  SomeHelper helper;
  
  def setUp() {
    this.helper = new SomeHelper()
    this.helper.accountService = Mock(AccountService)    
    this.helper.reportService = Mock(ReportService)
  }  

  def "make sure if the accountService findUser failed, then reportService reportRequest is called once"() {
    given:
    this.helper.accountService.restTemplate = Mock(RestTemplate)
    this.helper.accountService.restTemplate.postForEntity(_ as URI, _, String) >> {
      throw new CustomInvalidExceptionA()
    }

    when:
    this.helper.accountService.findUser("123")

    given:
    thrown CustomInvalidExceptionA
    1 * this.helper.reportService.reportRequest(*_) >> _
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: I commend you for trying to provide some context, but what is really bad about your question is that the code is incomplete, full of syntax errors, spelling errors (`Stirng` instead of `String` etc.) and inconsistencies (`postForEntity` in the test vs. `postEntity` in the code under test etc.), which makes it a pain in the rear end to copy, paste, compile, run and analyse your sample code. This was your free shot, and I am going to answer the question. But next time, please separately compile and run your stripped-down sample code to make sure it actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: BTW, be careful about case sensitivity, too. The method name in Spock is `setup()`, not `setUp()`. The latter does not even compile but yields an error with a hint to rename the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reproducible set of sample classes with several fixes in the existing code in order to make your pseudo code example compile and run in the first place. BTW, I replaced Lombok by explicit setters and getters for the purpose of this answer:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class Account { }
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class CustomInvalidExceptionA extends Exception { }
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class CustomInvalidExceptionB extends Exception {
  public CustomInvalidExceptionB(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class InventoryService {
  public void check(Item item) { }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class Item { }
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class ProcessRequest { }
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class Report { }
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

import java.net.URI;

public class RestTemplate {
  public void postForEntity(URI uri, Object o, Class<?> clazz) throws CustomInvalidExceptionA { }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class ReportService {
  public Report reportRequest(String accountId, Item item, Class<? extends Exception> message) {
    // some logics to make a report request
    return new Report();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class AccountService {
  public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return restTemplate;
  }

  public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public Account findUser(String acccountId) throws CustomInvalidExceptionA, CustomInvalidExceptionB {
    URI uri = null;
    try { uri = new URI("https://scrum-master.de"); }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

    this.restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, "x", Integer.class);
    // other logics
    throw new CustomInvalidExceptionB("Parent Account does not qualify");
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629;

public class SomeHelper {
  private InventoryService inventoryService;
  private AccountService accountService;
  private ReportService reportService;

  public ProcessRequest request(String accountId, Item item) {
    try {
      Account acct = this.accountService.findUser(accountId);
      this.inventoryService.check(item);
    }
    catch (CustomInvalidExceptionA | CustomInvalidExceptionB ex) {
      Report report = this.reportService.reportRequest(accountId, item, ex.getClass());
      System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getClass());
      //Other logics using report object
    }
    return new ProcessRequest();
  }

  public InventoryService getInventoryService() {
    return inventoryService;
  }

  public void setInventoryService(InventoryService inventoryService) {
    this.inventoryService = inventoryService;
  }

  public AccountService getAccountService() {
    return accountService;
  }

  public void setAccountService(AccountService accountService) {
    this.accountService = accountService;
  }

  public ReportService getReportService() {
    return reportService;
  }

  public void setReportService(ReportService reportService) {
    this.reportService = reportService;
  }
}
```

Now that we have something to compile and test, we can do this:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q75679629

import spock.lang.Specification

class SomeHelperTest extends Specification {
  SomeHelper helper

  def setup() {
    helper = new SomeHelper()
    helper.accountService = new AccountService()
    helper.reportService = Mock(ReportService)
    helper.inventoryService = Mock(InventoryService)
  }

  def "make sure if the accountService findUser failed, then reportService reportRequest is called once"() {
    given:
    helper.accountService.restTemplate = Mock(RestTemplate) {
      postForEntity(*_) >> {
        throw new CustomInvalidExceptionA()
      }
    }

    when:
    helper.request("123", Mock(Item))

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    then:
    1 * helper.reportService.reportRequest(*_)
  }
}
```

Please note:

- `AccountService` should not be a mock, if you expect its `findUser` method to run normally. Either use a normal instance or, if you need to verify interactions on it, a `Spy` (not necessary here). If you mock it, however, `findUser` will simply do nothing, especially not call `restTemplate.postForEntity`. ***Update:** See below for another solution in which you can mock this class.*
- It is "given, when, then", not "given, when, given".
- `thrown CustomInvalidExceptionA` does not make any sense, because that exception will be caught in `SomeHelper.request`.
- There are some other incorrect details in your Spock spec, which I am not going to elaborate on.

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJylV8Fu2zgQvesrBjpJXVdGW2yLRrsp2iJFc1iksNNzoUpjm41EKiTl2M3235eUKJmkJKfA5hDD5Aw5M-_NG7rO8rtsi1BgInLeVN-qTEjkiZBqg-2Rb0r2kNy_-fP1m7evX74NAlLVjEsQNcvvkjKj22RdY042JM8kYTQI8jITAtasws9Y1shvUUjAg0RaqGXbFh4DsAxh134EarHADQiUTR3FrRGYPfgbKD5YPlFs7SZZnrOGyjXyPcnRGL93Fl0HjjqZk_0_KqloZS865oTukUrGj57HtbeunX71eYRVdocgGo5ANiB3CF6YG0KLr0Ilt8lIicVC21BwQ-u-rfC-0dUkAvKsVLbAaI7hUKQtUXFczFdE5SvkLVZ1mUkr3dNafxBAzYT8xPgVlUQeo2ffYri8HDZBhcjZQ1vej42QrFIVyEpSXB1yrDW0702ddR26_-3Hw86Lj3cZReGLl6_ChammxCqOOwc5OFA2HH6rL6fRyOQFPJsENnGqp5Np8VExLZfw_H_8BUHdfC9JDh3nDdPgUafr7MwUaWiLYem3fT9M-aq0jOuMU7SWnNAtVCiE6voebtHoVuoX0746Thg-x-3b9owUkO_QgAdEI9imMjpFb49z_MJZrm7v-T026Hqy2zAK9CPbZwlFmXxdXacjc4vnfqAutZU3NJws4Ob7D8wlsAV81Gf89e5SH_bzZ9yRfR7EqTwdDbEjMIm4jDSomGa9VhIwlHGIZoz3pQ-jYrNQyggl25JcgGTQSk9mbgPTbK0tV-rKadvBXUjRCffJAk8sro9UZochHh8EV3jdIljwbFHa3wcxMxHakpX2umrDKTx_53A-IW5yR4SvhNO3cLLX27MnplYsffP3am6BalB9ikiL2Vbv4jZM1WOtKcu0y4UfFf_MqsJS2UThTspaXCyX7UB_bgZ6gWGcGjVW4zffQTSGEHSRLHFfqcBJhcN-hO0Z02VM3MZqmyo8KFW_phK3KoSWFnHac5Up5eaGrMHvDJUPUfgl40qFhmIXDIWaDBLuG2W5OYYz4mU9Mh4tYEea5g_41DL26OxO1tShy3hyD2Ynwniax5_WgoHAGnQzXvtKKHupONCC4g39gZHDmQYDg6GfdNIpeXtjGpxmuGHNnAz-e2ZSnd4Vjv71AZ-b1lYhOj3EQ6Iko1XFKB4yWR8Vy6uENTJROFBZ0ii8Wq1uVhcQwh8zTsvljcVBaISuvAmNtePASt9STBe6XjlP0I54pe7213ydm6LelNaNznmSxI7uTTxhn7rZI77KxX9Su5mMO2MqD--Ms93lZDB65J-_z-3GdthYC-Np43Tr3LixTzjT7t7EcX9rTFz1K_gP-seZSg). When running the spec, you see the error log printed to the console first. To see the actual test result, click on the "Result" tab:

[image: GWC test result]

---

**Update:** An alternative and maybe even better solution than before, if you want to mock the `AccountService`, assuming that the `Report report` variable is actually used later, as the source code comment implies, would be:

```java
public class Report {
  public void doSomething() { }
}
```

```java
  public ProcessRequest request(String accountId, Item item) {
    try {
      Account acct = this.accountService.findUser(accountId);
      this.inventoryService.check(item);
    }
    catch (CustomInvalidExceptionA | CustomInvalidExceptionB ex) {
      Report report = this.reportService.reportRequest(accountId, item, ex.getClass());
      System.out.println("ERROR: " + ex.getClass());
      // Other logic using report object
      report.doSomething();
    }
    return new ProcessRequest();
  }
```

You can test it like this, mocking everything but the class under test:

```java
class SomeHelperTest extends Specification {
  SomeHelper helper

  def setup() {
    helper = new SomeHelper()
    helper.accountService = Mock(AccountService)
    helper.reportService = Mock(ReportService)
    helper.inventoryService = Mock(InventoryService)
  }

  def "make sure if the accountService findUser failed, then reportService reportRequest is called once"() {
    given:
    helper.accountService.findUser(_) >> {
      throw new CustomInvalidExceptionA()
    }

    when:
    helper.request("123", Mock(Item))

    then:
    noExceptionThrown()

    then:
    1 * helper.reportService.reportRequest(*_) >> _
  }
}
```

Please note that in this case, the  `>> _` at the end of the last line is really essential in order to make the `reportRequest(*_)` method return a non-`null` stub response rather than the mock default of `null`. The idea to simply use a `Stub(ReportService)` would not work here, because on a stub you cannot verify interactions such as `1 *` , i.e. using a mock and making it return something other than `null` is the way to go.

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJylV01v2zgQvetXDHSSuq6CttgWjdos2iKL5lCksNNzoEq0zUYiFZJy7Kb97zuUKJmkJKfA5hJ4ON_z5o1dZ_ldtiFQkETmoqluq0wqIhKp8IHviFiX_CG5f_P36zdvX798GwS0qrlQIGue3yVlxjbJqiY5XdM8U5SzIMjLTEpY8Yp8JmVNxA2RCsheEVag2NaFxwAsRdi2_wIUFmQNkqimjuJWCcwbvAdGHiybKLZekyzPecPUiogdzQkqf8Ekow-O1DEQRBfj6S9toaNO2Y4wxcXBs7jy5Nrod19HWGV3BGQjCNA1qC0BL801ZcU3icWtM1qSYqF1GLipdZ-W5L7R3aQS8qxEXeAsJ-HQpA3FPM7nO5L0oaLbGC4ujBVgQMEf2s5-aqTiFdaTlbS43Oek1oP6YNrc1gTwsPWiiC6vKHzx8lW4MD1RpIrjzkANBowPTm90UBaNVF7As8nxJE4PomddCbdtqzGxszN4_j_-gqBuvpc0hw6-BjPwqGt2XmY6NCB8EP2x7ccpWyzLmM4YRSslKNtARaTEBe4hIBu9Fb0w7bvjpOHD1Y6247SAfEvMBIHqMbaljLzo53GNXwXPMXoP1bFCt16jmAXXW622WFM0BDRk8yPbZQkjKvm2vEpH7qS6IVVdZmpcSM2l-peLS6aoOkRoDY2gC7j-_oPkCvgCPmkf7_650M5-_oy7TZgf8lQfHLqwMzCFurA1UzN7eYXbPrR5yGaMhwt_zIh2ie2Ckm9oLkFxaFkmM9HAbGSrK5BIBWvXu0spOuJissETwtWBqWw_5OMPwaVYtwnWeDZE2Z8H3jIZCust7SnUHqf07B3ntnXvGOEkE_sBGXs6iqA7_TzrMbVy6clhYNPjUM1UnwLSYpYKurwNUvW5a8oy7WoRB8SfkeIsUScKt0rV8vzsrL3dz83tLkgYp1iXtsJLm28hGo8QdJMs5l9i4rQiw3tEWh_TbUzcxWqXKtwj9V8xRTaYQguLOO2xypHehQFr8CcX52MUfs0EstTQ7IITiedDwX2DmutDOENu1veJR2uwI87zb3lqKXtwdo9o6sBlfKQHtSNgPE4UT3PBAGA9dHOl-06gvkIMtEOZu--DTzMDM0O_6KRj-jZiak68hZo5Gvx14pLFQ74O__UJnzrpViM6PiT7BCmjZcUoHipZHRDlVcIbleAcmCpZFF4ul9fLcwjhrxkjBOH1EYTQSN15kxpvz4FR7GSJc47s1lhs6o61Z9Xj2EeYw7x8mc-BU7Cc4sGRnycB7nDixDfZpyJ7S4G1uBK_kvHWTNXh-Ti5eU4Fo-_6p-O5m9oeIkswvkTOJs-dItvDCSrwrpH7k2Mi1O_gP5USnBY).

Comment: Update: I added an alternative solution, arguably better than the first one.

Comment: Update 2: I also added a paragraph explaining the subtle use of `>> _`.

Comment: I'd remove the `noExceptionThrown()` as there are other conditions, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75679067/2145769 for the reasons

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of your other answer, but I prefer explicit rather than implicit specifications, so the reader does not depend on knowing the ins and outs of the test framework. In my explanation, I wanted to make a point about he OP's `thrown CustomInvalidExceptionA` being an wrong expectation. I therefore chose to explicitly state, that no exception is thrown in addition to the other condition. I intend to keep it that way. I disagree with the notion that `notThrown` or `noExceptionThrown` should be used only if they are stand-alone conditions.

Comment: Arguably, two separate `then` blocks would be better, though. I have just updated that code section.

Comment: >I disagree with the notion that `notThrown` or `noExceptionThrown` should be used only if they are stand-alone conditions - Why, this would mean that you'd have to basically add it to every test that doesn't use `thrown`, because you never want exceptions to happen in general.

Comment: No, it does not mean that I **have to** or even should do that at all. It means that I **can** add it whenever I see fit in order to convey my attention. It is nice to have a choice and syntactical means to make my spec tell a story. Those two methods exist as part of the Spock DSL for a purpose: to assert that certain exceptions have not been thrown or none have been thrown at all. If I want to make that an explicit part of my feature specification, I shall use it. That is part of what BDD is about, is it not?